# linux boot disable display/framebuffer update

Tags: linux, splash-screen, u-boot

My query is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186196/controlling-the-boot-screen-on-linux-embedded-app). I want a custom splash screen to be displayed during bootloader,kernel-boot and init phases of booting. I am able to add my logo for u-boot. How to show the same logo during kernel boot?

I think I have two options:
1) Disable kernel from updating/reinitializing the framebuffer so that u-boot's splash screen persists during kernel boot.
2)Let the kernel show the same splash so that the user does not observe the transition.

For the first option I tried the kernel command line options  "quiet    vga=normal     nofb     nomodeset     video=vesafb:off     i915.modeset=0" (All together). But this not working. The screen goes black after u-boot. Also I saw [this](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/LinuxSplashScreen)  option which says about a kernel configuration parameter (CONFIG_FB_PRE_INIT_FB) which does what I want. But this option is not available in my kernel (3.0) and I am not sure how to implement this or where to start.

For the second alternative I looked at [this](http://www.robgarrett.co.uk/pages/linux-things/arm-development/change-kernel-splash-screen.php) link which explains a method to hardcode the splash image to the kernel. But this is only compile-time configurable and I want run-time configuration. I think something like this is already implemented in Ubuntu. When ubuntu is booting, kernel messages are hidden by a color screen. How is this implemented?

Comment: *"The screen goes black after u-boot."* -- Probably because the MMU is being enabled.  You would have to ensure U-Boot allocated its framebuffer in a reserved section of physical memory that persisted through the initialization of virtual memory. *" I want to fully disable the kernel from updating the framebuffer/display."* -- The FB driver and the HW have to start in a known state to be synchronized.  Usually that common state is the quiescent state after a reset or full initialization.  You would have to modify drivers to start in an alternate state.

Comment: *"When ubuntu is booting..."* -- As you stated yourself, that splash screen is installed by Ubuntu, not the Grub bootloader.  That example does not fit with your original question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the question.

Comment: Now you've clarified your post to the point that you clearly contradict yourself.  First it's *" I want to fully **disable the kernel from updating** the framebuffer/display."* But later you'll  *"**let the kernel update** the framebuffer"*.  You cannot do both.